# maple returning multiple values at multiple times

Tags: return, maple

I would like to write a procedure in maple that returns a value at multiple times. This because the program I wrote takes rather long and it would be nice to consider certain results during the time it is running. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy. The quick-and-easy method is to include **print**, **printf**, or **lprint** statements in the code. The official and more-sophisticated method is to use the **userinfo** statement.